# change while(1) loop to busy wait in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, busy-waiting

```
void cpu_idle (void)
{
    /* endless idle loop with no priority at all */

    while (1) {
        void (*idle)(void) = pm_idle;
        if (!idle)
            idle = default_idle;
        if (!current->need_resched)
            idle();
        schedule();
        check_pgt_cache();
    }
}
```

this code existed in : "arch/i386/kernel/process.c" related to linux 2.4.18-14

this code is responsable of the ( cpu idle loop ).

the question is : can I change the while(1) loop with bust wait ?

Comment: please edit you question to include the code rather than a screenshot

Comment: Presumaby, 'pm_idle' exists so that you can 'override' the default idle handler function, something that probably halts the calling processor core.  Presumably, you could point 'pm_wait' at a function that does nothing except return, and  cpu_idle would then warm up the room by continually calling 'schedule' and 'check_pgt_cache'.   Even if that 'works', why anyone would want to do this is beyond me:(

Answer (score 1):

The loop here properly schedules processes so the system continues to run properly. Switching to a pure busy wait would lock up the system when the cpu goes idle, meaning other processes would cease to be scheduled. You definitely do not want that.